# Is ought a common word in American English?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, american-english

Are **ought** and **ought to** used in American daily speech ? Are these words common in American English? Maybe there is any other alternativs which are being used in American English?

Comment: You ought to do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly uncommon but it's moving in that direction.  "should", e.g. "He should go." rather than "He ought to go.", is the more common phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are common. "That is something we ought to do." "You ought not think about it from that angle."